# O que significa um "join table"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Eu estava lendo o livro Beginning Rails 4, quando me deparei com messe trecho na pagina 100.

> Let’s get back to the relationship between users and comments. You need to tell your user model that a user has many comments through its articles. Basically, you use the article model as a ***join table*** between users and comments. You achieve the linking using the has_many :through method.

O que significa esse conceito de join table ? Eu entendi no código o que ele faz, mas eu queria um conceito mais formal para isso.

Comment: Você sabe se o trecho se refere ao uso de `join table` em um SGBD?

Answer (score 3):

Eu imagino que os modelos devem ser algo assim:

```
User:
  id
  username

Article:
  id
  user_id
  title
  text

Comment:
  id
  article_id
  text
```

Assim, um usuário tem muitos comentários pertencentes as suas perguntas, só que isso acontece ***através*** da tabela *articles*.

Na declaração seguinte você informa isso para o Rails:

```
class User
  has_many :articles
  has_many :comments, through: :articles
end
```

Imagine que você tem um objeto `@user` de id `99`. Quando você usar `@user.articles` ele vai gerar um SQL assim:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM articles
WHERE user_id = 99
```

Não houve necessidade de JOIN.

Mas se você fizer `@user.comments` ele terá que fazer um JOIN:

```sql
SELECT comments.*
FROM comments
INNER JOIN articles
  ON comments.article_id = articles.id
WHERE articles.user_id = 99
```

Agora imagine que um comentário possa ter muitas respostas (*replies*):

```
class User
  has_many :articles
  has_many :comments, through: :articles
  has_many :replies, through: :comments
end
```

Ao fazer `@user.replies` ele fará dois JOINs:

```sql
SELECT replies.*
FROM replies
INNER JOIN comments
  ON replies.comment_id = comments.id
INNER JOIN articles
  ON comments.article_id = articles.id
WHERE articles.user_id = 99
```

### Conclusão

Portanto, "join table" é quando exite esse relacionamento indireto entre tabelas.